# ForceID while inserting products in PrestaShop 1.6 through Web Service

Tags: api, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I need to use "ForceID" feature for inserting custom product id (not the auto-incremented ids) through PrestaShop Web-Service.

ForceID feature works when uploading from the PrestaShop backoffice, but I am unable to do so from the web-service.

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528720/prestashop-adding-product-using-module-cant-force-product-id), but couldn't solve.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In `classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php` there's a method called `saveEntityFromXml($successReturnCode)`.

In this method you can try to remove this line:

```php
} elseif ($this->method == 'POST' && count($ids) > 0) {
    $this->setError(400, 'id is forbidden when adding a new resource', 91);
    return false;
}
```

I've not tested this code, please let me know if it works.